# .NET variable memory ALLOCATION versus memory USAGE

Tags: .net, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, primitive-types

This is a relatively simple question, but lately I’ve been looking into Huffman encoding and wanted to ask the pros here at SO.

If I declare a variable as `Int32`, does it necessarily use all the allocated memory?

That is, if my `Int32` has a value of `1`…

```cs
Int32 myVar = 1; // binary 00000000 0000000 0000000 00000001 (4 bytes = 32 bits)
```

…then are all 32 bits used, or are they only used as needed when the variables value requires the bits?

Seemingly, unless I used a low level language like C, C++, Rust, assembly, then Huffman encoding doesn't provide any compression of my data, albeit perhaps some very basic obfuscation of the original ASCII representation.

Please advise. I appreciate you thoughts on this subject.

Comment: Primitive values like `Int32` and `Single`/`float` that exist as local variables are not "allocated" like objects are - and certain short-lived temporary variables may exist only in registers and never in-memory.

Comment: Anyway, `Int32` is **always** 32-bits, so a value of `1` will consist of 31 zero bits and 1 set bit. That's how every programming language works because values and memory are at-most byte-addressable: no practical computer today has support for bit-level addressing.

Comment: _"Huffman encoding doesn't provide any compression of my data"_ - it does when you're serializing data to a bitstream. When your program reads a supplied entropy-encoded bitstream (e.g. Huffman-encoding, Arithmetic-encoding, etc) it will almost always need to decode/decompress the data in order to do anything with it: you can't extract an arbitrary decompressed 32-bit integer value from an arbitrary location in an entropy-encoded bitstream.

Comment: The resulting Huffman codes are self-terminating, that is, you can just put them next to each other, so frequent characters/values represented by short code would take less than their original.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dal.  That’s what I thought.  The serialization of the variable or serializable object instance containing the Huffman representation of the value would yield some savings, but wanted to check with you Pros first.  I didnt think the memory representation would yield any benefits.  Seemingly, though, Huffman could be used to create a domain specific language by using it with words and/or word phrases, kind of like tokenization; however, I dont think it would yield anything other than obfuscation in doing this too.